# How to format few computer at the same time

Tags: windows, networking, formatting

I have over 100 computers that I need to format. Do you have an idea to complete the transaction as quickly as possible? (The best of them all at once). For information computer farm is a mix between windows 98, 2000 and XP.

Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operating system is irrelevant here as it will need to be done at boot or outside from it, if you are talking about formatting the main hard drive.

I would recommend [Darik's Boot and Nuke](http://www.dban.org/) and use it on a USB drive, simply plop it in a machine and start, then move on to the next.

Alternatively, if you don't mind a bit of setup and these machines are networked, you can look at deploying Boot and Nuke to a PXE server and use [TFTPD32](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/) on Windows or any PXE server on Linux then you will be able to launch [Dban](http://www.dban.org/) across the network - just be careful that this is separated or other machines are not able to boot from it!

Comment: This solution seems to be perfectly adequate. Turnkey solution ! I'll try the solution quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean format or do you mean wipe completely?

The reason I ask is that it *sounds* like you're trying to wipe them prior to getting rid of them, if that's the case then I'd recommend you did more than just a format as your data could be recovered from a format quite easily. If you do need to wipe them then you really need to send a little man around with something like norton system tools making sure the data is properly wiped ok.

Comment: You're right, I'll get rid of !